Botrytis blight on peonies
My peony is 3 fo 4 feet high and wide.  It's covered in black spots.  I have it in a pot.  Will this fungus spread to my other peonies?  Should I cut it down and put it in the ground?  Thank you.

pictures please and your location, has it been wet and cool where you are?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
